# Ionic 4 android app not connecting to local node js server when running on real android device

Tags: android, socket.io, client-server, ionic4, nodejs-server

I am trying to implement a client-server communication for my Ionic 4 android app. I have a local node js server implementation on my pc and I am using socket.io to establish the communication. The problem is that when I am running the app on browser or on emulator the communication between the app and local server is ok but when I am trying to run the app on a real android device (samsung galaxy s9+) the app cannot connect to the local server. More specific the message 'User Connected' is not appeared on the server console to indicate that app is connected to the server and therefore user never gets back his userid.

Can anyone help me to find out why?

**Server side**

index.js

```
let app = require('express')();
let server = require('http').createServer(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(server);

// Allow CORS support and remote requests to the service
app.use(function(req, res, next)
{
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization');
  next();
});

// Set up route 
app.get('/', (req, res) =>
{
  res.json({ message: 'You connected to panic Shield server' });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

server.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening in http://192.168.x.x:' + port);
});

const uuidv4 = require("uuid/v4");

// User connected to the server
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  console.log('User Connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});

  socket.on('set-credentials', (credentials) => {
    let userId = uuidv4();
    ...
    // server informs user for his unique id
    socket.emit('your user id', userId);
    ...
  }
});
```

**Client side**

app.module.ts

```
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://192.168.x.x:8080', options: { secure: true } };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
],
...
```

home.page.ts

```
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';

constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

async ngOnInit() {
  this.socket.connect();
  ...
}

async connectToServer(name, surname, gender, speech) {
  const str = name.concat(' // ').concat(surname).concat(' // ').concat(gender).concat(' // ').concat(speech);
  this.socket.emit('set-credentials', str);
  this.socket.on('your user id', (data) => {
    this.userId = data.toString();
    // save the userId
    set('userId', this.userId);
    // Refresh the page
    window.location.reload();
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to ping your server address from another computer in your local network ? To make sure it's accessible from your whole local network and not only from localhost.

Comment: I started my server and he is listening in http://192.168.x.x:3001. I wrote the address on browser of another computer in my local network. I have an error message 'This side can't be reached' ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. That means my server is only accessible from my localhost? How can I make him accessible to my whole local network?

Comment: Have you tried to run your server on `0.0.0.0` instead of your ip address ? This is how my NodeJS server is configured, and it is accessible from local network at `192.168.x.x:port`

Comment: In my case, the firewall of my pc doesn't allow any other device on local network connect to the server. When I turned off the firewall the connection between client-server was established!

Comment: Oh yes I forgot about the firewall, is everything working fine now ?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In my case, the firewall of my pc doesn't allow any other device on local network connect to the server. When I turned off the firewall the connection between client-server was established!